# quotation marks in Jquery creates error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute this:

```
$("<li class="   last-item SunItem-8").before("</ul><ul>");
```

but because of that " I am getting an error how can I capture this but not error out?

Comment: Maybe you should show us how the finished HTML should look, as what you're doing doesn't really make much sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector isn't a valid jQuery selector.

```
$('<li class="last-item SunItem-8"/>').before("</ul><ul>"); // note the added '/>' at the end of the selector
```

This way you create a new li-Element. If you don't want to create a new one but want to select an existing one, you should use:

```
$('li[class="last-item SunItem-8"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<li class="   last-item SunItem-8">').before("</ul><ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access with

```
$('li[class=last-item SunItem-8]').somefunction();
```